# How to bind json string in observableArray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, knockout.js

In my controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetCountryList() {
     return Json(new {data = db.Country.ToList()},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

in my ko:

```
self.GetCountryList = function () {
    $.getJSON("/ProfileCore/GetCountryList", function (result) {
        self.LocationList(result.data);
        console.log(self.LocationList());
    })
};
```

select html:

```
<select data-placeholder="Location" class="chosen-select" style="width:100%;" tabindex="2" data-bind="options:LocationList, optionsText:'CountryName', optionsValue:'Id', value:Location"></select>
```

when I view the console log this is the result:
[image: console result]

the result is there is no data in select option. any suggest in how to do this in the right way? thanks

Comment: What do you mean on "no data in select option"? There is no items in it if you open the dropdown? Or your current Location is not preselected?

Comment: no items in dropdown. your right that's what I meant

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. self.LocationList is an observableArray, I assume. Not a plain observable. Can you perhaps make a little fiddle with mocked data? It will be easier to debug.

Comment: yes it's an observablearray. ok I will create a fiddle for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
// Create an object 
var Country = function (Id, Name) {
        self = this;
        self.Id = Id;
        self.CountryName = Name;
    }

// Create a mapping object
    var mapping = {
        'LocationList': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new Country(options.data.Id, options.data.CountryName);
            }
        }
    }

// Create the view model
function AViewModel()
{
  var self = this;  
    self.LocationList = ko.observableArray();
    self.Location = ko.observable("2");

    // Map the json to the view model
    $.ajax({
       url:"/echo/json/",
       data:data,
       type:"POST",
       success:function(response)
       {
         self.LocationList = ko.mapping.fromJS(response, mapping, self);
       }
    });


}

var viewModel = new AViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

jsFiddle with mock json call:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/Tnyqp/10/